# If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property error

Tags: jaxb

I am getting below exception when I am trying to marshel below java classes to below expected xml.

**Exception:**
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parent>
    I am the parent element of mixedtype.
    <child>I am the child element</child>
</parent>
```

**Parent.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
public class Parent{

    protected List<Child> child= new ArrayList<Child>();
    protected List<String> text= new ArrayList<String>();

    @XmlElementRef(name="child",type=Child.class)
    public List<Child> getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    @XmlMixed
    public List<String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setChild(Child value) {
        this.child.add(value);
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        this.text.add(value);
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child {
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above the XML I tried this and seems to work fine for me:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parent>
    I am the parent element of mixedtype.
    <child>I am the child element</child>
</parent>
```

Parent.class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Object> textContent;

    @XmlElement(name = "child")
    private String child;
}
```

My Main class:

```
public class JaxbExampleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("parent.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final Parent parent = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Parent.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(parent.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(parent, System.out);
    }
}
```

Following is the output that I am getting:

```
Parent(textContent=[
    I am the parent element of mixedtype.
    , 
], child=I am the child element)
<parent>
    I am the parent element of mixedtype.
    
<child>I am the child element</child>
</parent>
```